# pycord asyncio blocking everything of the discord event loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio, pycord

I'm trying to create a pseudo-terminal via discord, basically with the `/connect` command a new process is started (i.e: Powershell) and the user can interact with it via the discord chat and get back the output in real time. The bot sends a message once in response to `/connect` and then it is edited automatically each time the user sends a new message with the content of the process' stdout/stderr. I'd like for the message to be updated every 0.5 seconds because if a command has a long execution time it can get boring.

Right now the code works with sending the output to print() instead of to discord messages. I tried MANY different ways of making this work with discord messages but I was unable to. When I make read_stdout() async and try to call it with asyncio unsing various techniques and callbacks the behaviour is the same: While there is new bytes in process.stdout everything works, then the shell waits for input and stops sending data to stdout, at this moment everything blocks in the bot, including the listeners and events.

Here is the complete code of the Instances cog

```py
import subprocess
import threading
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.commands.context import ApplicationContext


def read_stdout(process: subprocess.Popen, message: discord.message.Message):
    # Right now this works in real time with the console using print()
    # Try running the bot in a private discord server and doing /connect
    # Then type some powershell commands in the discord chat and look at the console output
    # you should see the powershell process's stdout
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line.rstrip())
        # message.edit(line.rstrip())
            

class Instances(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: discord.Bot):
        self.bot = bot        

    @discord.command(name="connect")
    async def connect(self, ctx: ApplicationContext):
        powershell = subprocess.Popen(
            f"powershell",
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            universal_newlines=True
        )

        message = await ctx.channel.send('Output should be here')
        await ctx.respond('Ignore this: Placeholder response')

        # This thread reads from the stdout of the process infinitely, the issue persists when 
        # modifying the read_stdout function to be async and edit the discord message instead
        threading.Thread(
            target=read_stdout,
            args=(powershell, message)
        ).start()

        # Infinite loop that waits for messages from user and sends them
        while True:
            command: discord.message.Message = await self.bot.wait_for('message')
            powershell.stdin.write((command.content + "\n"))
            powershell.stdin.flush()

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.message.Message):
        print(f'Message received from chat: {message.content}')
```

Thanks

Comment: You need a separate thread for waiting of input from the process or create and use an `asyncio.subprocess.Process`  instead which provides standard streams suitable for asynchronous access.

Comment: I can't use other threads because otherwise an Exception will be raised because the discord wrapper doesn't permit making API calls from other threads except the one the API is running on

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe or the other way around: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread